# Create page navigation in Apostrophe CMS

Tags: apostrophe, nunjucks, apostrophe-cms

Trying to create 'nephew' pages for a hover-over primary navigation bar -
 example website structure:

- the website has pages A, B, C, D
- under section A there are pages A1, A2, A3
- under section B there are pages B1, B2, B3
- I'm currently on page A

The experience I'm trying to create is this:

a) I have a top navigation showing A, B, C (easy - I've done this)

b) My current page A is highlighted (easy - I've done this)

c) When I HOVER over menu A a list of 'child' pages A1, A2, A3 appears (easy - I've done this)

The thing I can't do is this:

d) Displaying child pages outside the current ancestors - i.e. when I HOVER over menu B a list of 'nephew' pages B1, B2, B3 appears under B

I've used the various Apostrophe loops to do (b) and (c):

```
{% for ancestor in data.page._ancestors %}
```

But I've run out of options for the 'nephew' pages - essentially I want to do this:

- give the code a page name
- have the code display the equivalent of `data.page.title` but for the specific page, not the current page (i.e. I'd pass the name of page B to this code for it to generate B1, 2, 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in mentioned in the [building navigation](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/building-navigation.html) tutorial, you can configure Apostrophe to load the children of each ancestor to any depth.

Since the home page qualifies as an ancestor, loading its children to a depth of 2 gives you what you need:

```
modules: {

  // ... other configuration ...

  'apostrophe-pages': {
    filters: {
      // Grab our ancestor pages, with two levels of subpages
      ancestors: {
        children: {
          depth: 2
        }
      },
      // We might want grandchildren of the current page, too
      children: {
        depth: 2
      }
    }
    // other apostrophe-pages options like `types` ...
  },

  // ... other configuration ...
}
```

Now you can iterate over `data.home._children`, and over the `._children` of each of those "tab" pages in turn as well, giving you the "nephews" you wanted.

This works if you're more deeply nested too, because we're loading the children of all ancestors to a depth of 2. Just keep looking for `._children` properties where you would hope to see them.

Comment: Thanks - yes, that makes more sense. I'd previously been trying to get to the cousin pages from the CURRENT page using data.page, then climbing up the tree and across it, which wasn't working.

Answer (score 1):

have you gone through this guide? It covers dropdowns for page tree-based navigation http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/getting-started/building-navigation.html

Comment: Thanks Stuart, yes I used that guide and it's great as it DOES allow me to get these relationships in the CURRENT tree:
- children 
- me
- parents
- aunts/uncles
- grand parents 

However it does NOT unfortunately let me travel down an adjacent tree to get the nephew/nieces (i.e. showing the children of an 'adjacent parent' as a hover-over menu when I hover across each of the 'adjacent parents')